# Multiple time intersection in php

Tags: php, time, overlapping

I have a situation that I can not wrap my head around at the moment. Multiple Time Overlaps. I've seen many posts on two [times that overlap](http://pastebin.com/f62002cb5) but nothing that has multiple times overlapping.

Here's the data I would like to place in:

```
<?php
//RUN EACH Class Selection for Monday
foreach($class as $Classes){
    $time[] = array($ClassStartTime, $ClassEndTime, $classID);
}

OverLapFunction($time);
?>
```

Which would then post the classID and Overlapping Amount. Has anyone run into this situation before? Or figured out how to do this?

Comment: I still don't understand what you want from `OverLapFunction`. Do you need to know if _all_ the dates overlap at some point, or they cover a continuous time frame, do you want the time point where a maximum of classes intersect? Maybe you find the first part of this article http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=greedyAlg of use.

Comment: Lets say I have:
    Class A: Monday: 8:00AM - 11:00AM 
    && 
    Class B: Monday: 10:00AM - 11:30PM
    &&
    Class C: Monday: 12:00PM - 4:00PM
    &&
    Class D: Monday: 3:00PM - 6:00PM
Then I would like the OverLapFunction to output Class A and Class B Overlap ALSO Class C and CLass D Overlap. 

Ps. I have everything is a db. Not sure if that could help with the logic. I'm trying to throw errors whens a user selects classes that overlap times.

Comment: What sort of format is the time in? Unix TS? YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say your data is like this:

```
$classes = array(
    array(
       'name' => 'A',
       'day'  => 'Monday',
       'start'=> '08:00AM',
       'end'  => '11:00AM',
    ),
    array(
       'name' => 'B',
       'day'  => 'Monday',
       'start'=> '10:00AM',
       'end'  => '11:30AM',
    ),
    array(
       'name' => 'C',
       'day'  => 'Monday',
       'start'=> '12:00PM',
       'end'  => '04:00PM',
    ),
    array(
       'name' => 'D',
       'day'  => 'Monday',
       'start'=> '03:00PM',
       'end'  => '06:00PM',
    ),
);
```

You just need a nested `foreach`, like this:

```
$overlap = array();
foreach ($classes as $class1) {
    foreach ($classes as $class2) {
        if ($class1['day'] != $class2['day'] || $class1 == $class2) continue;
        if (strtotime($class1['start']) <  strtotime($class2['end']) &&
            strtotime($class1['start']) >= strtotime($class2['start']))
        {
            $array = array($class1['name'], $class2['name']);
            sort($array);
            if (!in_array($array, $overlap)) $overlap[] = $array;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, it compares each class to all classes. If `$class1` start time is less than `$class2` end time **and** `$class1` start time is more than `$class2` start time: they overlap. Keep in mind that each class will be compared to each other twice (e.g.: A to B, B to A), so if it doesn't match on the first pass, it will in the second.

This'll give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => B
            [1] => A
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => D
            [1] => C
        )

)
```

If you were to change class `D` to:

```
array(
   'name' => 'D',
   'day'  => 'Monday',
   'start'=> '10:00AM',
   'end'  => '03:00PM',
),
```

...effectively overlapping all classes, you'd get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => B
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => B
            [1] => D
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => C
            [1] => D
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => D
        )

)
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks. I have one more question... if the campus is different I must leave 1 hour time difference between courses, would this be easy to implement into this?

Comment: @Jsu: In theory, doing `< strtotime($class2['end']) + 3600` in the `if` there should work.

Comment: Amazing netcoder, you saved me a huge head ache & a deadline. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** This function is more pseudocode and you'll need to implement it yourself; It returns groups of overlapping classes. I've written it like this for you to understand it better. If you need more explanation on why we need to sort the times first, let me know.

```
function OverLapFunction($time) {
    sort_by_start_time($time); // ensures that we don't have
                               // overlapping groups at the end
    $groups = array(); // groups have starting time, ending
                       // time and items they contain
    foreach($time as $item) {
        // if we don't find a group to put this item in, we create a new one
        $found = false;
        foreach($groups as $group) {
            // basically the whole if statement looks for overlapping between
            // the group and the current item
            if(($item['start_time'] >= $group['start_time'] 
                && $item['start_time'] <= $group['end_time']) ||
                ($item['end_time'] >= $group['start_time']
                &&  $item['end_time'] <= $group['end_time']))
            $group['items'][] = $item; // add the item to its group
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
        if(!$found) { // no group that fits this item; create a new one
            $groups[] = array(
                'start_time' => $item['start_time'], // start and end times
                'end_time' => $item['end_time'],     // are the item's
                'items' => array($item),
            );
        }
    }
    return $groups;
}
```

Oh, and for the record: if you have a user that selects some classes and you need to ensure that no two of his chosen classes overlap, you can reduce the problem to the one you already have a grasp on:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($item); $i++) {
    for($j=0; $j<count($item); $j++) {
        if($i == $j) {
            continue;
        }   
        if(times_overlap($item[$i], $item[$j])) {
            do_something(); // the user has chosen incorrect classes
        }
    }
}
```

Note: the problem above can be made better performance-wise if you sort the items by starting date and just check if two consecutive array elements overlap.